# Как не делать лишний раз объявление одного и того же метода с квалификатором const? C++

Tags: c++

Есть некий класс, который содержит метод `map`:

```
// Не нужно говорить про говнокод. Это лишь минимальный пример
// показывающий проблему
template<typename Func>
/*type*/ map(Func &&func)
{
  return func(arg);
}
```

Функция func может принимать Arg как по const ссылке, так и нет. То есть как может изменять значение переменной-члена класса, так и не может. Из-за этого мне нужно объявить метод map дважды - с квалификатором const и без. А если я захочу, чтобы в зависимости от ref-квалификатора объект arg еще и мувился в func, то придется сделать 4 почти одинаковые версии метода map.

И если версии для l-value и r-value еще отличаются в вызове Std::move/std::forward, то версии для const и не-const не отличаются от слова вообще:

```
template<typename Func>
/*type*/ map(Func &&func) &
{
  return func(arg);
}

template<typename Func>
/*type*/ map(Func &&func) const &
{
  return func(arg);
}
```

Однако если оставить только метод с const-квалификатором, то при передаче аргумента Arg в func на него также навесится квалификатор const и передаваться он будет уже по константной ссылке и изменить объект arg не получится.

Вопрос: как мне избежать 4-х объявлений одного и того же метода, если использовать универсальную ссылку нельзя?

Comment: Объявите два разных метода.

Comment: @user7860670 И чем это должно помочь лишний раз не объявлять const версию? В лучшем случае число имплементаций останется таким же. В худшем и на другой метод придется по версии писать

Comment: Тем что будет понятно, что это *разные* методы, каждый из которых заслуживает отдельную реализацию.

Comment: *"Вопрос: как мне избежать 4-х объявлений одного и того же метода, если использовать универсальную ссылку нельзя?"*  -- у меня получается только с универсальной ссылкой в статическом методе. Почему нельзя?

Comment: @AlexGlebe потому что у меня толкается в функцию переменная-член класса, а не аргумент функции, который можно передать по универсальной ссылке

Comment: ну посмотрите рабочую попытку https://godbolt.org/z/Kx5jGb7da функцию map я сделал статической и ничего не мешает то что переменная в составе класса. Единственная проблема это изменение декларации этой функции, но кажется единственное решение на сегодняшний день.

Comment: @AlexGlebe я не могу взять и поменять функцию на статичную, добавить ей аргументов или изменить поведение. Я пытаюсь реализовать [monadic optional](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0798r0.html) из первой редакции предложения. Но вы мне подкинули идею. Я реализовал НЕ статичную функцию `map_impl`, которая принимает универсальную ссылку и реализует сам алгоритм. А map лишь вызывает его. Да, я не избавился от лишних объявлений map, но кода значительно меньше, чем при копипасте. Если не сложно, оцените решение, что скажете? [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xfb4bobvb)

Comment: @AlexGlebe хотя из-за магии с шаблонами и концептами я чувствую, что получился лютейший говнокод. Но вроде работает

Comment: ничего не помогает, код так и остался с четырьмя функциями. оставьте всё как есть.

Answer (score -1):

Ждем C++23 с его [шаблонным `this`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r6.html).

А пока ждем, макросы спасут мир:

```
struct A
{
    std::string arg;

    QUAL_MAYBE_CONST_L_R(
        template <typename F>
        decltype(auto) map(F &&func) QUAL
        {
            return std::forward<F>(func) QUAL_IN(static_cast<decltype(arg) QUAL>(arg));
        }
    )
};
```

Идея такая: все что внутри `QUAL_MAYBE_CONST_L_R` дублируется 4 раза, и в каждой копии `QUAL` заменяется на одно из: `&`, `const &`, `&&`, `const &&`.

Из-за технических ограничений, если `QUAL` находится внутри круглых скобках, то перед каждой такой открывающей скобкой должно стоять `QUAL_IN`.

Раскрывается в:

```
struct A
{
    std::string arg;

    template <typename F>
    decltype(auto) map(F &&func) &
    {
        return std::forward<F>(func)(static_cast<decltype(arg) &>(arg));
    }
    template <typename F>
    decltype(auto) map(F &&func) const &
    {
        return std::forward<F>(func)(static_cast<decltype(arg) const &>(arg));
    }
    template <typename F>
    decltype(auto) map(F &&func) &&
    {
        return std::forward<F>(func)(static_cast<decltype(arg) &&>(arg));
    }
    template <typename F>
    decltype(auto) map(F &&func) const &&
    {
        return std::forward<F>(func)(static_cast<decltype(arg) const &&>(arg));
    }
};
```

[А вот и сами макросы](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/imp-re/blob/master/src/macros/qualifiers.h):

Я положил три варианта: 1.  /`const`, 2. `const &`/`&&`, 3. Собственно, `&`/`const &`/`&&`/`const &&`.

```
#pragma once

/* Example usage:
 *   QUAL_MAYBE_CONST( QUAL int &GetX() QUAL {...} )
 * This expands to:
 *         int &GetX()       {...}
 *   const int &GetX() const {...}
 *
 * Note that if `QUAL` appears inside of parentheses, those parentheses must be preceeded by `QUAL_IN`.
 * Example:
 *   QUAL_MAYBE_CONST( QUAL int &Foo QUAL_IN(QUAL int &x); )
 * This expands to:
 *         int &Foo(      int &x);
 *   const int &Foo(const int &x);
 *
 * We also have `QUAL_CONST_L_OR_R(...)` that gives `const &` and `&&`,
 * and `QUAL_MAYBE_CONST_L_R` that gives `&`, `const &`, `&&`, and `const &&`.
 */
#define QUAL_MAYBE_CONST(...) \
    IMPL_QUAL      ((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)()) \
    IMPL_QUAL_const((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)())
#define QUAL_CONST_L_OR_R(...) \
    IMPL_QUAL_const_lref((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)()) \
    IMPL_QUAL_rref      ((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)())
#define QUAL_MAYBE_CONST_L_R(...) \
    IMPL_QUAL_lref      ((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)()) \
    IMPL_QUAL_const_lref((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)()) \
    IMPL_QUAL_rref      ((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)()) \
    IMPL_QUAL_const_rref((IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)())

#define QUAL )(IMPL_QUAL_identity,
#define QUAL_IN(...) )(IMPL_QUAL_p_open,)(IMPL_QUAL_null,__VA_ARGS__)(IMPL_QUAL_p_close,)(IMPL_QUAL_null,

#define IMPL_QUAL_null(...)
#define IMPL_QUAL_identity(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define IMPL_QUAL_p_open(...) (
#define IMPL_QUAL_p_close(...) )


#define IMPL_QUAL_body(cv, m, ...) m(cv) __VA_ARGS__

#define IMPL_QUAL(seq) IMPL_QUAL_a seq
#define IMPL_QUAL_a(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_b)
#define IMPL_QUAL_b(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_a)

#define IMPL_QUAL_const(seq) IMPL_QUAL_const_a seq
#define IMPL_QUAL_const_a(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(const,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_const_b)
#define IMPL_QUAL_const_b(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(const,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_const_a)

#define IMPL_QUAL_lref(seq) IMPL_QUAL_lref_a seq
#define IMPL_QUAL_lref_a(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(&,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_lref_b)
#define IMPL_QUAL_lref_b(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(&,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_lref_a)

#define IMPL_QUAL_const_lref(seq) IMPL_QUAL_const_lref_a seq
#define IMPL_QUAL_const_lref_a(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(const &,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_const_lref_b)
#define IMPL_QUAL_const_lref_b(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(const &,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_const_lref_a)

#define IMPL_QUAL_rref(seq) IMPL_QUAL_rref_a seq
#define IMPL_QUAL_rref_a(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(&&,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_rref_b)
#define IMPL_QUAL_rref_b(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(&&,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_rref_a)

#define IMPL_QUAL_const_rref(seq) IMPL_QUAL_const_rref_a seq
#define IMPL_QUAL_const_rref_a(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(const &&,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_const_rref_b)
#define IMPL_QUAL_const_rref_b(...) __VA_OPT__(IMPL_QUAL_body(const &&,__VA_ARGS__) IMPL_QUAL_const_rref_a)
```

Злоупотреблять этим не стоит, потому что внутри макроса теряется информация о номерах строк, и отлаживаться построчно не получится.

Comment: Я смотрю макросы не в почете. :/

Comment: ну типа, не знаю ни одного человека, кто любил бы макросы) Я выше предложил свое решение. От количества объявлений не спасло, но сильно сократило код и копипасту. Да и на с++-way больше похоже, как по мне

Comment: @ComeInRage Теперь одного знаете. :)